# Access Report TextBox gives #Type Error in Totals

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am pulling my hair out as cannot figure out how to fix this
I am summing 12 text boxes which make up a financial year on an
MS -Access Report.

I get a #Type Error on 2 of the textboxes and the Totals TextBox, If I add them up Jan to Dec the errors occur in the Jan and Feb Text Box and the Total, if I sum from Dec to Jan the error occurs in the Nov and Dec Text Boxes and the Total like this:

```
=[R_OthSpnd_1_Dec]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Nov]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Oct]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Sep]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Aug]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Jul]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Jun]+[R_OthSpnd_1_May]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Apr]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Mar]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Feb]+[R_OthSpnd_1_Jan]
```

which leads me to think it has something to do
with the order that the TextBoxes process the function, I checked the function
and the textboxes do seem to process from the highest months where there is data back to January?

If I wrap the functions in the textBoxes in an Nz function and or the Totals it seems to make no difference?

Any idea how I can get them to Total correctly?

Totaling Dec to Jan
[image: Totaling Dec to Jan]

Totaling Jan to Dec
[image: Totaling Jan to Dec]

VBA Function looks like this:

```
Function GetValue(ByRef Lookup_Value As String, ByRef Company_Name As 
                String, ByRef Mth_Value As String, ByRef Year_Value As String)

On Error GoTo Err_GetValue

Dim mydb As DAO.Database
Dim rs_1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs_2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs_3 As DAO.Recordset
Dim Get_SQL_1 As String
Dim Get_SQL_2 As String
Dim SQL_Return_Value As String
Dim fnDataReturn As String
Dim Lookup_Column_Name As String
Dim Lookup_Values As String
Dim X As Long

Set mydb = CurrentDb
Dim strTypeOfData(3)

For i = LBound(strTypeOfData) To UBound(strTypeOfData) - 1

    strTypeOfData(0) = Lookup_Value & "External"
    strTypeOfData(1) = Lookup_Value & "Internal"
    strTypeOfData(2) = Lookup_Value & "Forecast"

    Get_SQL_1 = "SELECT [SQL_Statement] FROM tblMappingsOtherSpend WHERE [Lookup] ='" & strTypeOfData(i) & "';"
    Get_SQL_2 = "SELECT [Lookup_Column] FROM tblMappingsOtherSpend WHERE [Lookup] ='" & strTypeOfData(i) & "';"
    Set rs_1 = mydb.OpenRecordset(Get_SQL_1)
    SQL_Return_Value = rs_1.Fields("SQL_Statement").Value
    SQL_Return_Value = SQL_Return_Value & Year_Value & Mth_Value & "';"

    Set rs_2 = mydb.OpenRecordset(Get_SQL_2)
    Set rs_3 = mydb.OpenRecordset(SQL_Return_Value)

    Lookup_Column_Name = rs_2.Fields("Lookup_Column").Value

    If rs_3.RecordCount = 1 Then
        fnDataReturn = CLng(rs_3.Fields(Lookup_Column_Name).Value)
        If fnDataReturn <> 0 Or fnDataReturn <> "" Then
            GetValue = CLng(fnDataReturn)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If

    GetValue = 0

    Next i

    rs_1.Close
    rs_2.Close
    rs_3.Close

    Set rs_1 = Nothing
    Set rs_2 = Nothing
    Set rs_3 = Nothing
    Set mydb = Nothing

    Exit_GetValue:

    Exit Function

    Err_GetValue:

    GetValue = 0
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Else

        GoTo Exit_GetValue
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you have a space in one of the text boxes so Try this `=Trim([R_OthSpnd_1_Dec])+Trim([R_OthSpnd_1_Nov])+...` etc.

Comment: Hi, you might be on the right track, I tried the above, it eliminated one of the # Type errors in Nov but Dec and the Total box remained?

Comment: Glad to here that! Somehow your text-boxes are not really empty or completely numeric ( strange though..)  so.. instead of Trim you can try [Val function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/val.php)

Comment: Solved the issue Changed the GetValue =0 to GetValue =Null And wrapped all the TextBoxes being added in an Nz function forcing it to zero if null, I was also causing the line item text box to appear (not in the pictures) if the total was not zero or blank when I changed this to look up in a table with a Dlookup according to certain criteria in the report it removed the type error from Dec, thanks for your help you pointed me in the right direction